# Fotorama scripts block another scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I tried to use your -- truly excellent! -- Fotorama js/jQuery scripts and they worked, but in the same time they blocked all other js/jQuery scripts added to my HTMLs.
My site is: http://www.taraka.pl
I tested the site: http://www.taraka.pl/proba_galerii -- but now your scripts are disabled there.
With compliments
Wojciech Jozwiak

Comment: I have a similar issue when loading AngularJS and jQuery in the same project...Try changing the order in which the script load... it could be an issue with the version of jQuery or some other components interfering each other.

Comment: I an trying to place a Fotorama gallery in a separated pop-up window. Thank you, Diego Carrascal.

Comment: you could show us how are you loading your pop-up window...

Comment: Yes, I did: [link](http://www.taraka.pl/dmtwalker_bohater_tysiacu_twarzy) (entirely in Polish) -- open and click the button "Pokaz galerie" below the photo.

Comment: your variable `x` in `ShowFotoramaInNewWindow(aTitle,w,h)` trows an error when creating it `var x=f[0].innerHTML;` because `var f=document.getElementsByClassName("fotorama_data");` does not return anything... it's undefined, that error is preventing the rest from execute.